# how to insert and retrieve unicode data in foxpro database from vb dotnet

Tags: vb.net, unicode, foxpro

I am developing a small desktop application. In this application i have to simply insert unicode data in foxpro database and retrieve the same in a listview.
In SQL Server it worked perfect :-

```
insert into LOG (name,adrs) values(N'"& TxtName.Text &"',N'"& TxtAdrs.Text &"')
```

But when i wrote the same thing to insert data in foxpro table(.dbf file), it shows an error

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Syntax error.
```

Can anybody tell what i am doing wrong.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check this out, see if it helps: http://kb.softescu.ro/programming/vbnet/working-with-dbf-file-dbase-iv-from-vb-net-create-dbf-insert-into-select-from/

Comment: This only tells how to create dbf tables pragmatically. No sign for unicode characters.

Comment: Like this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43aaa4d5-b59d-46ac-9468-12c8dd8a6dc2/writing-non-ascii-charaters-to-a-dbf-file?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Good suggestion.. But i want to store data in dbf file by INSERT INTO command and retrieve data by SELECT * FROM command..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On VFP side the SQL should look like this:

```
insert into LOG (name,adrs) values('value1','value2')
```

But you cannot store Unicode in VFP table. It only can contain ANSI data along with it's codepage.

Comment: This works good, but when i retrieve the same data it shows ????? in listview column. How can i convert it into a real string ??

Comment: Have you tried debugging it on the .NET side to see whether it's actually returning a string and the problem really lies in your Listview?

Comment: I dont know how to do it in VB. You need to convert data from ANSI to Unicode.

Comment: Guys, Foxpro is not compatible to store or retrieve unicode data so i took SQL Server database and now i am tension free... Thanks for every thing you all did for me. God Bless You All....